# Integral zero does implies function zero on boundary?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral, compactness

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be a compact and convex set. Consider a function $f: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable on $C$ such that
$$\int_C \, f(x) \, d\lambda(x) \, = \, 0 $$
where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Is it possible under this assumptions to show that $f \equiv 0$ on the boundary $\partial C$? Otherwise, under which conditions, it holds that?

Any help/suggestion would be appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider the simplest (nontrivial) case of $m=1$ and $C$ being a closed interval. What can you say in that case?

Comment: Unless the interior of $C$ is empty, you can always modify $f$ to make the integral zero,   without changing the values on $\partial C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot show that $f$ vanishes on the boundary.
Consider the example $m=1$, $C=[-1,1]$, $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Thanks, nice counter-example!